# how access to values of combobox in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

Values in ComboBox:

[image]
I want to access values of ComboBox. I define equal for each item, for example "عالی" is equal to 100 and etc.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390462/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-name-value-how

Comment: show code where you define the items values.

Comment: string sel = GridView_Karkard.SelectedRows[0].Cells["myCombo"].Value.ToString();
               
              
                switch (sel)
                {
                    //case "عالی": Globals.val = 100; break;
                    case "عالی": val = 100; break;
                    case "خیلی خوب": val = 99; break;
                    case "خوب": val = 98; break;
                    case "متوسط": val = 97; break;
                    case "ضعیف": val = 96; break;
                    default: val = 0; break;
                }

Comment: ok, this is not a way to bind items, you have to use `datasource`

Comment: I hope you read this. I am sorry about what happened with your question today. I understood what you were asking, but sometimes people on SO are more interested in proving how clever and superior (they think) they are than actually helping someone else. As far as I am concerned, I give answers to try to help newbies.  Please don't let the trolls here discourage you.